# What is the difference between Windows.history.back() and history.back() for Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os

I am developing some apps for FFOS , and I don't know what is difference between `Windows.history.back()` and `history.back()` and where is it recommend to use each one for FFOS. What is the recommendation for each of the following:

- Hosted apps?
- Package apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vedsa, both calls refers to the same method, being 'window' optional.

For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history) you can find more about windows properties and methods

**Which one is recommended for Hosted x Packeged apps?**

As I mentioned earlier, they are calling the same method, and can be considered aliases. Having said that, there is really no difference on which you're going to use if it's a **hosted** or a **packaged** app.

The main difference between hosted vs packaged apps is that in the first, you're hosting the package on your end, providing just a url to it so that the Marketplace has a reference to it. On the other hand, when building a packaged app, you're handing a full self-containing app packaged to the marketplace, so that they can host it for you and distribute on the Marketplace.